# Can i call VFunc from outside of the object?

Tags: c++, virtual

I like the results of this code but i was curious, is it possible to call B::VFunc() from main()? I know writing `B::VFunc();` inside of C will call it but is it possible to call the function from outside of the object?

http://ideone.com/Dg8aa

```
#include <cstdio>
class I { public: virtual void VFunc()=0; };
class B : public I { public: void VFunc() { printf("B\n"); } };
class C : public B { public:  void VFunc() { printf("C\n"); } };

int main(){
    C v;
    B&i = v;
    i.VFunc();
}
```

output:

```
C
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#include <cstdio>
class I { public: virtual void VFunc()=0; };
class B : public I { public: void VFunc() { printf("B\n"); } };
class C : public B { public:  void VFunc() { printf("C\n"); } };

int main(){
    C v;
    B&i = v;
    i.B::VFunc();
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/MfyYJ

Comment: I did not know you could do that. +1

Comment: You don't even need a `B` reference, it can be applied directly to the `C` object: `v.B::VFunc();`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes, it can. I just copied OP's code and applied the solution to it, but you're totally right :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can resort to slicing:

```
C v;
B i = (B)v;
```

http://ideone.com/YVI2T

The dynamic type of `v` is lost, so `B::VFunc` is called.

Comment: wow +1. I guess static_cast are evil as well :( -edit- other ppl: Other ways to answer my question are welcome

Comment: Why slicing an object(which implies copying), when you can do it with no overhead? What if B contains pure virtuals and can't be instantiated?

Comment: @fontanini I didn't know you could.

Comment: The problem with the slicing approach is that if `VFunc` has side effects, those would be applied to a different object than the original